# Difference between Azure Worker Role & Azure Automation?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-automation

Are these 2 totally different things or are they roughly same/similar in what they can accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Worker Role is your own set of virtual machine in a "application farm".  You can run any code on them in a distributed fashion.  Typically, you write business code to run on these servers (ie: order processors, customer emailers, cloud-to-premise synchronizers, etc)

Azure Automation is meant more for automating administrative tasks such as:

- Reboot your servers once per day.
- Deploy bits to staging environment.
- Run connectivity tests against a particular resource, etc.

Azure Automation is written in Powershell which is great for accomplishing small administrative tasks.  I would not want to write a complex order processing system in Powershell though :O

Furthermore, with Worker Roles you kind-of have decent control over the VMs that run your code.  Can install third-party components on them, access local storage, basically do whatever a regular C#/VB.NET program can do.  Automation is a service to automate admin tasks.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! So, essentially, Worker Roles are restricted to VM's running on Azure? I'm looking for s good solution to run simple SQL jobs for Azure SQL (i.e. not VM's).

Comment: Yes. Automation maybe a decent solution for simple sql jobs